# Как удалить файлы с определенным именем в нескольких папках? Python

Tags: python-3.x, ос

Есть архив состоит из папок, названых датами.
Необходимо пробежаться по каждой папке архива и удалить определенные файлы формата xlsm.

Понял только как удалить определенный файл, а как несколько нет(

```
import os

path = "C:/Archive/01-10-2021"
a = 'AL010.xlsm'        # Нужно удалить AL010, M_4613,SG010, и др. при том, что существуют другие файлы начинающиеся с AL*,M_*,SG*
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if a in i:
        full_file_path = os.path.join(path, a)
        os.remove(full_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал через `glob` (позволит задать шаблон), используя `pathlib`.

Пример:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('C:/Archive/01-10-2021')
for file_name in path.glob('AL*.xlsm'):
    file_name.unlink()
```

Если поиск нужно сделать в папках с неопределенной вложенностью, то вместо `glob` использовать `rglob`, тогда поиск файла будет от текущей папки в `path` и в вложенных папках

Comment: Прости за глупость, но как быть если файлы начитаются не только на AL*?

Comment: Добавить еще `*`: `'*AL*.xlsm'`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)

Comment: @dizel, ок :) если мой ответ помог, то проголосуйте и примите его :)

Comment: Помог, но так и не понял как мне впихнуть несколько значений для удаления...Потом понял что не совсем корректно задал вопрос...Нужно удалить AL010, M_4613,SG010, при том, что существуют другие файлы начинающиеся с AL*,M_*,SG*.

Comment: @dizel, тут вижу такие варианты 1) сделать цикл над `for file_name in path.glob(file_name_pattern):`, где будут шаблоны файлов перебираться 2) сделать перебор всех файлов через `for file_name in path.glob('*.*'):`, а уже в цикле искать подходящие файлы. Если с каким-то из вариантов есть трудности, могу накидать код в ответе после `UPD`